# my font face is not showing in browsers

Tags: css, font-face

i want to use a certain font in my web pages.

I have done this is my css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf');
}
```

I publish it and now I view the site on another PC.

The font looks like Time Roman.

I click F12

I look at the properties and it tells me it is using Roboto

I open notepad and look for Roboto font.

it is not there..?

Please advise?

Comment: A font added with `@font-face` is only available on the page which references that CSS, in the browser. So, it wouldn't show up in Notepad. You may want to check the Network tab to make sure it's successfully loading that TTF font if the font looks like Times New Roman.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Comment: the @import line goes at the top of your style sheet and the font-family you add to whatever element you like.

Comment: does not seem to work. When I look at the network tab is does not say t has been down loaded anywhere :(